# Auditoria en laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel-5

Tiene laravel un sistema de auditoria para los usuarios de un webapp? Debo guardar tods la actividad de un usuario.

Si un usuario ingresa a un app de laravel, debo guardar toda su actividas, a que páginas entra, si ingresa, edita o elimina un registro, cuales son los valores que editó,cuales reporte visualiza,  etc.

Adicionalmente, debo tener una manera de visualizar esas actividades y hacer seguimiento.

Todo lo que encuentro es laravel logging, pero dirigido a errores, no a actividad de los usuarios

Comment: La pregunta es amplia y basada en opiniones lo cual generaría su cierre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel-activitylog provee funciones fáciles de utilizar para registrar la actividad de los usuarios: https://github.com/spatie/laravel-activitylog:

En SO, Shrinath propone una solución utilizando Laravel Observers: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46725235/audit-users-actions-in-php-laravel

Traduzco la propuesta de SO a petición de otros usuarios. A tener en cuenta:
Los usuarios de la pregunta referenciada eran de un rol específico y las acciones a registrar tenían efecto en otros usuarios. En caso de optar por esta opción sería necesario adaptar su aplicación al tipo de usuarios y acciones a registrar en el proyecto.

> Debes crear una nueva tabla para almacenar las acciones llevadas a
>   cabo por los admins (en este caso, usuarios).
>
> Tu nueva tabla debería tener campos para almacenar los siguientes
>   detalles:
>
> quien - El usuario/a que lleva a cabo la acción
>
> qué - qué acción se ha llevado a cabo
>
> cuándo - cuando ha tenido lugar la acción
>
> sobre quién - sobre qué otro usuario se ha realizado la acción  Ahora
>   tienes que crear observers en todos los modelos que quieres auditar
>   (usuarios)
>
> ver - [laravel Observers][1]
>
> Tu observer debería tener todos los métodos para acciones que el admin
>   realiza (crear, guardar, actualizar, eliminar)
>
> El método de tu observer debería registrar la acción realizada por el
>   admin en la tabla que has creado previamente.
>
> El usuario super admin puede ver entradas en esta tabla pra auditar a
>   los admins de nivel inferior
>
> [1]: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#observers

Comment: Muchas gracias,  en este caso, voy a inclinarme por la primera opción - laravel-activitylog y estudiaré la segunda

Comment: Genial, Juan Felipe. Si la respuesta te sirve y te parece bien, puedes marcarla como solución :-) Bienvenido!

Comment: Se te agradece el apoyo pero 2 comentarios: responder a preguntas mal plantedas y basadas en opiniones no es bien visto ya que eventualmente terminan cerradas, por otro lado aunque diste una *respuesta* esta se basa únicamente en enlaces lo cual es considero de baja calidad

Comment: En cambio tu aporte mejoraría de calidad si por ejemplo traduces la pub. en inglés que enlazas

Comment: Hola Aprendiz, 
Antes que nada, muchas gracias por tus sugerencias.
Lo había pensado  pero el primer enlace es la url de un repo de git, y la publicación de SO responde a una pregunta diferente - aunque en parte útil- a la que se pregunta  aquí, por lo que he pensado que incluir su traducción podría resultar confuso.

Comment: Esta respuesta es muy mala, no entiendo cómo puede tener dos votos positivos. Repsonder con enlaces a una pregunta que de hecho está mal planteada no ayuda en nada a los futuros visitantes.